# Has the SC ever overturned a decision twice?

Tags: us-supreme-court

> The nation's high court has overturned 236 rulings in its history, some of which marked sea changes in American society and rule of law.

Well, has it ever overturned a decision which itself overturned a previous decision?  Thus has case C overturned case B which overturned case A?

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking. Do you mean has SCOTUS overturned a prior decision (B overturns A), and then overturned the latter decision(C overturns B)?

Comment: Also, SCOTUS does not really evaluate evidence, except for limited cases where it has original jurisdiction.

Comment: To reiterate Damila: please [edit] your question to clarify it.  Specifically, when you say "that decision", which decision are you referring to?

Comment: @MartinBonner see edit

Comment: @Damila see edit

Comment: I have edited the question in a way which I believe makes it clearer.  If you don't like this rewording, feel free to revert.  (In particular note the change to the title - as originally asked, the answer to the question in the title is given in the first line of your quote.)

Comment: @MartinBonner vacuously. And I'll reward a +50 bounty for the finder of a case.